# retrieve result for an optional field in spring jpa query

Tags: java, spring

I am a newbie to Spring and java, I have a scenario, where i like to query like below:

when i have a po.id value, i can search like this below:

form service :

```
prescriptionOrderRepository.searchPharmacyOrders(args);
```

I am writing my spring query like this:

```
@Query(value = "select po from PrescriptionOrder po WHERE po.pharmacyId = :pharmacyId  "
            + "AND po.id = :idValue  AND po.active = :active ORDER BY po.createdAt DESC")
    Page<PrescriptionOrder> searchPharmacyOrders(@Param("pharmacyId") Long pharmacyId,
            @Param("idValue") Long idValue, Pageable pageRequest, @Param("active") Boolean active);
```

Suppose if i have to requirement, po.id is an optional field means, how can write query for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always expect the params, they're either null by default, or I get a value and it has to match. So for a parameter :idValue your query has

```
... AND (po.id = :idValue OR :idValue is null) ...
```

When e.g. you come from a Controller class, using GET variables, you can always use them as default null, or you're getting a value and it has to match.

In your example, that query in total...

```
WHERE (po.pharmacyId = :pharmacyId AND po.id = :idValue AND po.active = :active
```

Changes to:

```
WHERE ((po.pharmacyId = :pharmacyId OR :pharmacyId is null) AND (po.id = :idValue OR :idValue is null) AND (po.active = :active OR :active is null)
```